# How to remove div elements with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have a webpage, and all I'm interested is the div with id "content", i.e:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

How do I remove all the other div elements, and just display the div I want?

Comment: Are you sure you want to *"remove all the other div elements"*? From the entire page?

Comment: I suppose you only mean to remove sibling `div` elements, ie not ancestors (that would mean removing the `#content` node itself) nor descendants...

Comment: what if your div is enclosed in another div?

Comment: @thirtydot yes, because I'm only interested in the content of the webpage, if the webpage has like #nav, #footer, #header which are parent nodes, I don't want it... all I want is the #content and its child elements...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var all_div_nodes = document.querySelectorAll('div'),
    len           = all_div_nodes.length,
    current       = null;

while( len-- ) {
    current = all_div_nodes[len];
    if( current.parentNode ) {
        if( current .id !== 'content' )
            current .parentNode.removeChild( current );
    }
}
```

If you can afford using a library like jQuery, this would be even more trivial:

```
$('div').not('#content').remove();
```

Comment: use `document.getElementsByTagName` instead of `document.querySelectorAll` in for support in browsers that do not support the later.

Comment: will `$('div').not('#content').remove();` not remove a parent which is a div?

Comment: @jAndy caching the `all_div_nodes[len]` would perform much faster and why do need to check for the presence of parentNode for each div? (this would be required only if your html document is malformed)

Comment: @Itay: `.not()` filters the current set and removes all matches.,

Comment: I don't like this...seems way more verbose and complicated than needed...and not particularly compatible to boot.

Comment: @MooGoo: downvoting is not necessarily needed because you "don't like it". However, please introduce your better version in your answer.

Comment: I downvoted because of `querySelectorAll`. This code will not work in IE <= 7, and there's no advantages to using it over `getElementsByTagName` in this case. Also, this would remove div elements that are children of "content", is that what is wanted?

Comment: @MooGoo: that is at least better. Anyway, you are self-contradictory. In your first comment you complained about "too complicated" etc, but you should realize that filtering out descendet div's would cause even more code to invoke.

Comment: "simple as possible but no simpler". For what this code does it is overly complex. With more concise code, you could add descendant filtering and still end up with about the same length as what you currently have. And this doesn't address the issue with `querySelectorAll`, what is better about it.

Comment: @MooGoo: If you worry so much, just implement all that concise code in an answer and I'll upvote that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the sibling DIVs, using jQuery, you can write:

```
$("#content").siblings("div").remove();
```